# AsyncTask #3 Android crashes with doInBackground when posting data to tomcat server

Tags: java, android, tomcat, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I am trying to post data from android to application server.When the user register himself, he clicks register button.And AsynTask cycle starts from here.After that, the fragment should be replaced with download fragment.

Here is the code for Register.java

```
public class Register extends Fragment{

 private Button register;
 private EditText tcno,username,confirmpassword,password;
   /**
     * Define Click listener for the button.
     */
 private static final String SERVICE_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8084/ClinicWebApp/rest/routine";
 Context thiscontext;

    private OnClickListener registerClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
              SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(v.getContext());
            Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("verification_code", tcno.toString());
            editor.commit();
            //Dbye kaydet user bilgilerini



            if (tcno.equals("") || username.equals("") ||  
                    password.equals("")||confirmpassword.equals("")) {
              //  Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Please enter in  
                    //all required fields.",
                //        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            //post to web

            WebServiceTask wst = new WebServiceTask(WebServiceTask.POST_TASK, 
                getActivity(), "Posting data...");

            wst.addNameValuePair("tcno", tcno.getText().toString());

            wst.execute(new String[] { SERVICE_URL });

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            DownloadRoutines downloadFragment = new DownloadRoutines();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, downloadFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.register, null);
        contentView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        register = (Button)contentView.findViewById(R.id.register);
        tcno=(EditText)contentView.findViewById(R.id.tcnoEditText);
        username=(EditText)contentView.findViewById(R.id.usernameEditText);
        password=(EditText)contentView.findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText);
        confirmpassword=(EditText)contentView.findViewById  
                (R.id.confirmPasswordEditText);
        thiscontext = container.getContext();

        return contentView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        register.setOnClickListener(registerClickListener);
    }
    public void handleResponse(String response) {

        System.out.println(response);



    }

    private class WebServiceTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        public static final int POST_TASK = 1;
        public static final int GET_TASK = 2;

        private static final String TAG = "WebServiceTask";

        // connection timeout, in milliseconds (waiting to connect)
        private static final int CONN_TIMEOUT = 3000;

        // socket timeout, in milliseconds (waiting for data)
        private static final int SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 5000;

        private int taskType = GET_TASK;
        private Context mContext=null;
        private String processMessage = "Processing...";

        private ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        private ProgressDialog pDlg = null;

        public WebServiceTask(int taskType, Context mcontext, String processMessage) {

            this.taskType = taskType;
            this.mContext = mcontext;
            this.processMessage = processMessage;
        }

        public void addNameValuePair(String name, String value) {

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
        }

        private void showProgressDialog() {

         //   pDlg = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
          //  pDlg.setMessage(processMessage);
           // pDlg.setProgressDrawable(mContext.getWallpaper());
           // pDlg.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
           // pDlg.setCancelable(false);
            //pDlg.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

          //  hideKeyboard();
           // showProgressDialog();

        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            String url = urls[0];
            String result = "";

            HttpResponse response = doResponse(url);

            if (response == null) {
                return result;
            } else {
                System.out.println(response);
                try {

                    result = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());


                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
                }

            }

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {

            handleResponse(response);
            //pDlg.dismiss();

        }

        // Establish connection and socket (data retrieval) timeouts
        private HttpParams getHttpParams() {

            HttpParams htpp = new BasicHttpParams();

            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(htpp, CONN_TIMEOUT);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(htpp, SOCKET_TIMEOUT);

            return htpp;
        }

        private HttpResponse doResponse(String url) {

            // Use our connection and data timeouts as parameters for our
            // DefaultHttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(getHttpParams());

            HttpResponse response = null;

            try {
                switch (taskType) {

                case POST_TASK:
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                    // Add parameters
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    break;
                case GET_TASK:
                    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
                    response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
                    break;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);

            }

            return response;
        }

        private String inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {

            String line = "";
            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();

            // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            try {
                // Read response until the end
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    total.append(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
            }

            // Return full string
            return total.toString();
        }

    }

      }
```

I can send the value to tomcat web server with rest, but when I click the button the application crashes and gives me the following logcat:

```
03-20 16:54:10.214: E/AndroidRuntime(2488): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
03-20 16:54:10.214: E/AndroidRuntime(2488): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while 
executing doInBackground()
03-20 16:54:10.214: E/AndroidRuntime(2488): at 
android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
03-20 16:54:10.214: E/AndroidRuntime(2488): at 
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
03-20 16:54:10.214: E/AndroidRuntime(2488): at    
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
03-20 16:54:10.214: E/AndroidRuntime(2488): at   
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
03-20 16:54:10.214: E/AndroidRuntime(2488): at   
android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
03-20 16:54:10.214: E/AndroidRuntime(2488): at  
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-20 16:54:10.214: E/AndroidRuntime(2488): at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-20 16:54:10.214: E/AndroidRuntime(2488): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
03-20 16:54:10.214: E/AndroidRuntime(2488): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-20 16:54:10.214: E/AndroidRuntime(2488): at  
com.example.androidrest_client.Register$WebServiceTask.doInBackground(Register.java:176)
03-20 16:54:10.214: E/AndroidRuntime(2488): at  
com.example.androidrest_client.Register$WebServiceTask.doInBackground(Register.java:1)
03-20 16:54:10.214: E/AndroidRuntime(2488): at   
android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-20 16:54:10.214: E/AndroidRuntime(2488): at  
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-20 16:54:10.214: E/AndroidRuntime(2488): ... 4 more
```

Cause of the error line:

```
 result = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
```

What can be the cause for this?Why does the application crash?

Comment: doInBackground(Register.java:176) line 176 of Register.java.. it crash for a null pointer

Comment: @MacroAcierno how can I solve it?

Comment: Post the line and we will see

Comment: Well, if inputStreamToString is null it means he don't get anything from the http request.. or something similar.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno What does it mean?Do you say the problem related with HttpResponse method?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're getting a null response from the server. Investigate this section:

```
        HttpResponse response = null;

        try {
            switch (taskType) {

            case POST_TASK:
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                // Add parameters
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                break;
            case GET_TASK:
                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
                response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
                break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
        }
```

You're either getting a null response from the server or you're running into an exception before the response can get set.